# Google API key no response on Google+ API

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-one

I took following code :

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/";

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p",
"params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer",
"groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));


$curl_results = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$parsed_results = json_decode($curl_results, true);

echo $parsed_results[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'];

?>
```

[From Here](http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/)

And tried it in my test page , it works flawlessly.
Then i went to google developer console , registred new app , selected Google+ API and rendered new keys (browser,server, android) and tried to use each of them with this script. None work.

What am i doing wrong here ? Can someone point out ?

I tried playing around with keys , like giving them domain from which they should be invoked , etc. But that doesnt seem to be the problem. Apache is not generating any error logs, and in developer-console (networking) i am getting 200 , in response : **NO RESPONSE**

Can someone point out what am i doing wrong , is there something in google developer console that i am missing ?

Comment: This is what i did , on more then few occasions ... And there is no option for "public" in developer console , or i am just blind.

Comment: As i have said , i checked it read it carefully , in my console there is no option [PUSH] under API & AUTH. Do you mind trying this if its not hassle and tell me does it work for you?
I am starting to suspect only this key will work for this , as i have seen some more examples that are using this exact KEY.

Comment: This is an undocumented private API that is not for third-party developer use. You should stick to the [supported APIs](https://developers.google.com/+/).